# Ozone in Fruit and Vegetable Cleaning and Storage

Tags: research

During post harvest storage, surface infections on produce can spread and cause significant losses of the crop. The use of ozonated water for washing and disinfecting can reduce these losses and maximize returns. Ozonated water is a convenient way to wash fruit and vegetables and offers the following advantages over traditional chlorine based sanitizers.
The level of dissolved ozone in the water can be accurately and simply controlled using ORP (Oxidation Reduction Potential) measurement.
The disinfectant effect of ozone is not dependent on the pH level of the water.
Ozone will leave no residue on the produce that may affect taste or reduce shelf life.
Ozone is generated as required and therefore needs no special storage.
Ozone has no ongoing chemical purchase or disposal costs.
Ozone leaves no residue in the water and therefore makes reuse simply a matter of filtration.
Are these claims correct or not?

Comment: 1. This is off topic here. You can ask on either [skeptics.se] or [sustainability.se] but make sure you read there first what is on topic and how a good question is written. Here are some hints. 2. Don't write a [wall of text](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text) 3. It sounds like you are quoting something - say so, and include the link to what you quote from.